# Randomly Timeout(TimeSpan) doesn't work in Rx

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive, reactive-programming

The earlier post seems not very clear, so after some testing, I reopened this post with much more simplified words, hope somebody could help.

My **singleton** observable was turned from **multiple** source of I/O events, means they're **concurrently** raised up in underlying, based on testing (to prove Rx is not thread safe) and RX design guideline, I made it **serialized**, see that `lock(...)`:

```
public class EventFireCenter
{
    public static event EventHandler<GTCommandTerminalEventArg> OnTerminalEventArrived;
    private static object syncObject = new object();
    public static void TestFireDummyEventWithId(int id)
    {
        lock (syncObject)
        {
            var safe = OnTerminalEventArrived;
            if (safe != null)
            {
                safe(null, new GTCommandTerminalEventArg(id));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the singleton Observable:

```
public class UnsolicitedEventCenter
{
    private readonly static IObservable<int> publisher;
    static UnsolicitedEventCenter()
    {
        publisher = Observable.FromEventPattern<GTCommandTerminalEventArg>(typeof(EventFireCenter), "OnTerminalEventArrived")
            .Select(s => s.EventArgs.Id);
    }

    private UnsolicitedEventCenter() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Publisher property to start observe an observable sequence. 
    /// </summary>
    public static IObservable<int> Publisher { get { return publisher; } }
}
```

The scenario of `Subscribe(...)` can be described by following code, you can see the `Subscribe(...)` could be called concurrently in different threads:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < concurrentCount; i++)
    {
        var safe = i;
        Scheduler.Default.Schedule(() =>
        {
            IDisposable dsp = null;
            dsp = UnsolicitedEventCenter.Publisher
                .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(8000))
                .Where(incomingValue => incomingValue == safe)
                .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
                //.Take(1)
                .Subscribe((incomingEvent) =>
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref onNextCalledTimes);
                    dsp.Dispose();
                }
                , ex =>
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref timeoutExceptionOccurredTimes);
                    lock (timedOutEventIds)
                    {
                        // mark this id has been timed out, only for unit testing result check.
                        timedOutEventIds.Add(safe);
                    }

                    dsp.Dispose();
                });
            Interlocked.Increment(ref threadPoolQueuedTaskCount);

        });
    }
```

*As pointed out times by experienced people, call `Dispose()` in `OnNext(...)` is not recommended, but let's ignore it here since the code was from production.*

Now the problem is randomly that `.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(8000))` is not working, the `ex` was never called, anyone could see any abnormal in the code?

for testing, I setup the stress testing, but so far, I didn't reproduced it, while in production, it appeared several times per day.  Just in case, I pasted all the testing code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rx
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // avoid thread creation delay in thread pool.
            ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(200, 50);
            // let the test run for 100 times
            for (int t = 0; t < 100; t++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("======Current running times: " + t);

                // at meantime, 150 XXX.Subscribe(...) will be called.
                const int concurrentCount = 150;
                // how many fake event will be fire to santisfy that 150 XXX.Subscribe(...).   
                const int fireFakeEventCount = 40;

                int timeoutExceptionOccurredTimes = 0;
                var timedOutEventIds = new List<int>();
                int onNextCalledTimes = 0;
                int threadPoolQueuedTaskCount = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < concurrentCount; i++)
                {
                    var safe = i;
                    Scheduler.Default.Schedule(() =>
                    {
                        IDisposable dsp = null;
                        dsp = UnsolicitedEventCenter.Publisher
                            .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(8000))
                            .Where(incomingValue => incomingValue == safe)
                            .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
                            //.Take(1)
                            .Subscribe((incomingEvent) =>
                            {
                                Interlocked.Increment(ref onNextCalledTimes);
                                dsp.Dispose();
                            }
                            , ex =>
                            {
                                Interlocked.Increment(ref timeoutExceptionOccurredTimes);
                                lock (timedOutEventIds)
                                {
                                    // mark this id has been timed out, only for unit testing result check.
                                    timedOutEventIds.Add(safe);
                                }

                                dsp.Dispose();
                            });
                        Interlocked.Increment(ref threadPoolQueuedTaskCount);

                    });
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Starting fire event: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff"));

                int threadPoolQueuedTaskCount1 = 0;
                // simulate a concurrent event fire
                for (int i = 0; i < fireFakeEventCount; i++)
                {
                    var safe = i;
                    Scheduler.Default.Schedule(() =>
                    {
                        EventFireCenter.TestFireDummyEventWithId(safe);
                        Interlocked.Increment(ref threadPoolQueuedTaskCount1);
                    });
                }

                // make sure all proceeding task has been done in threadPool.
                while (threadPoolQueuedTaskCount < concurrentCount)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }

                // make sure all proceeding task has been done in threadPool.
                while (threadPoolQueuedTaskCount1 < fireFakeEventCount)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }



                Console.WriteLine("Finished fire event: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff"));
                // sleep a time which >3000ms.
                Thread.Sleep(8000);

                Console.WriteLine("timeoutExceptionOccurredTimes: " + timeoutExceptionOccurredTimes);
                Console.WriteLine("onNextCalledTimes: " + onNextCalledTimes);
                if ((concurrentCount - fireFakeEventCount) != timeoutExceptionOccurredTimes)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Non timeout fired for these ids: " +
                           Enumerable.Range(0, concurrentCount)
                               .Except(timedOutEventIds).Except(Enumerable.Range(0, fireFakeEventCount)).Select(i => i.ToString())
                               .Aggregate((acc, n) => acc + "," + n));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("faild to output timedout ids..."); }
                    break;
                }

                if (fireFakeEventCount != onNextCalledTimes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("onNextOccurredTimes assert failed");
                    break;
                }

                if ((concurrentCount - fireFakeEventCount) != timeoutExceptionOccurredTimes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("timeoutExceptionOccurredTimes assert failed");
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("DONE!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class EventFireCenter
    {
        public static event EventHandler<GTCommandTerminalEventArg> OnTerminalEventArrived;
        private static object syncObject = new object();
        public static void TestFireDummyEventWithId(int id)
        {
            lock (syncObject)
            {
                var safe = OnTerminalEventArrived;
                if (safe != null)
                {
                    safe(null, new GTCommandTerminalEventArg(id));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class UnsolicitedEventCenter
    {
        private readonly static IObservable<int> publisher;
        static UnsolicitedEventCenter()
        {
            publisher = Observable.FromEventPattern<GTCommandTerminalEventArg>(typeof(EventFireCenter), "OnTerminalEventArrived")
                .Select(s => s.EventArgs.Id);
        }

        private UnsolicitedEventCenter() { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Publisher property to start observe an observable sequence. 
        /// </summary>
        public static IObservable<int> Publisher { get { return publisher; } }
    }

    public class GTCommandTerminalEventArg : System.EventArgs
    {
        public GTCommandTerminalEventArg(int id)
        {
            this.Id = id;
        }

        public int Id { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: And this is the "much more simplified words" version of your question?? I gave up half-way thru - it's just too hard to understand what you're trying to do. You need to write some brand-new code that minimally displays the problem you are having so that we can help you solve it. Right now this question is just way too much hard work to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the `Timeout` is not triggering because you have it *before* the `Where` filter.  This means that all events are flowing through and resetting the timer, and then most of the events get filtered by the `Where` clause.  To your subscribing observer, it will seem like it never gets a result and the timeout never triggers.  Move the `Timeout` to be after the `Where` and you should now have a system that times out individual observers if they do not get their expected event on time.

Comment: this sounds really reasonable, it also explains why the stress testing can't reproduce the problem, since the testing always have an ending, while in production environment, it always have events raise up to refresh that timer.     I didn't noticed that method's sequence to cause the problem, I'll try and let you know.